# is it possible to style delete button on a material-ui's Chip component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

No problem with styling chip label or background color, or chip itself. But seems like that delete round button inside chip is a svg icon. Is there any way I can change color of it?

Comment: Can you provide any more information about your issue, scenario, etc.?

Comment: I just want to style delete button inside material-ui's Chip component. this is my issue. don't even know what additional info can be provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by overriding the default theme colors for Chip:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';    

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme({ chip: { deleteIconColor: 'red' } })}>
// ...
```